# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it, works on localhost but not my local IP

Tags: c#, tcpclient, windows-firewall

I'm working on a TCP client in C#. It works fine when I send packets to my server if the IP it's sending data to is 127.0.0.1, but when I change it to my actual ipv4 address it breaks and gives me this error message:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I've checked netstat -a and I can see that a service is listening on port 5000 (my application), I've also opened up the port in my firewall (5000-5500).

What further actions can I take before I have to contact the sysadmin to see if something else may be blocking my connection?

Here is my TCP client:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestLockedConsoleAppNet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_Locked);
            TestTCP();
            while (true) { }
        }

        static void SystemEvents_Locked(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Locked");
            }

            TestTCP();
        }

        static void TestTCP()
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 5000); // <-- works fine. But when I change the IP to my ipv4 address, it breaks.

            Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Locked");

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", "Message");

            data = new Byte[256];

            String responseData = String.Empty;

            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

`netstat -na | find "5000"` provides this when I run listening to my local IPv4:

> TCP    10.146.200.78:5000     0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

Comment: Can you post your netstat result? Maybe it's listening only on the endpoint `127.0.0.1:5000`?

Comment: Added edit that shows the port in use when running my tcp server listening to my local ipv4 address.

Comment: Actually. That was the problem. It had previously been listening to localhost rather than my ipv4 address... god damnit, I'm stupid.

Comment: The first step is being honest with one's self ;)